# Update State in SwiftUI Programatically

Tags: swift, swiftui, state, textfield

I'm new to Swift and coming from React I'm sure I'm thinking about state wrong. I have a View that has a simple Text Input. Based on external events I'd like to update the contents of this Field to match the current Pasteboard contents.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var input: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {            
            VStack( alignment:.leading, spacing: 16, content:{
                TextField("#000000", text: $input)
            })
            .padding()
        }
    }
    
    func update(){
        let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
        let firstItem = pasteboard.pasteboardItems![0];
        let string = firstItem.string(forType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(rawValue: "public.utf8-plain-text"))!
        NSLog(string);
        input = string;
    }
}
```

Everything seems to work except that `input = string` does not update the contents of the Field, (nor the state variable) in the debugger I can see when the function is called but it doesn't affect the Field contents.

Do I just need to call some different setState function? or is this not possible?

Comment: Where are you calling `update`?

Comment: Force unwrapping and hard-coded index subscripting are strongly discouraged. `update()` can be reduced to `guard let string = NSPasteboard.general.string(forType: .string) else { return } input = string`. And this is Swift, no trailing semicolons.

Comment: This view is part of a menuItem. I'm calling `update` from the `NSMenuDelegate` on `menuWillOpen` it feels a bit hacky. All I need is the textfield to update to the contents of the pasteboard every time the menu is opened, and then allow the user can change it from then on. Maybe theres a better event to use on the view itself?

Answer (score 0):

`body` is only called when a state is set if it was previously read. It is unusual to be in this situation and usually a sign your `View` hierarchy or source of truths are not correct, however you can fix it by faking a read like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var input: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = input
```

Fyi the reason `$input` is not considered a read is that is syntactic sugar for `Binding(get: {}, set {})`, i.e. a pair of closures.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, it seems like the view doesn't set state variables when it's hidden so instead of calling `update` from object that was showing the view (at the same time as showing it), it works if I simply call it every time the view appears with:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var input: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {            
            VStack( alignment:.leading, spacing: 16, content:{
                TextField("#000000", text: $input)
            })
            .padding()
        }
        .onAppear {
            update()
        }
    }
    
    func update(){
        guard let string = NSPasteboard.general.string(forType: .string) else { return }
        input = string
    }
}
```